# Word Press Post_Status to change at specific time and not on post_date time

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site that handles meetings scheduled for a board. The site breaks these meetings down into Upcoming and Past meetings. Once a meeting has changed from post_status = scheduled to post_status = future, it is moved to the Past meetings page.

I wanted to know if anybody had any ideas on how I might be able to change this process to only change the post_status at specifically 17:00 on that day. I can't change the scheduled date because the scheduled date is used to display the time of the meeting on the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wp cron, triggering daily to update your post status. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Answer (score 0):

You could change the process so that you can change the scheduled date to control when the meeting gets moved into Past Meetings so set the scheduled time to 17.00 on that day.

Then you could use custom meta data field to display the time of the meeting.